# How to get my script working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-api

I've got a fairly complicated script which uses Google Geolocation API and Timezone API and I want to integrate it into my wordpress page. The script includes showing a Google map.

Where to start? I tried just pasting the code into the wordpress page code editor but that doesn't work.

Comment: Make it its own file and `enqueue` it in your theme's functions.php.

Comment: How would it be called from a specific page?

Comment: `if ( is_page('some_page_id') ) { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the JS libraries and the JS function in the head section of your page. You could do this by adding the code to the header.php file of your WP template, for example.

Example 4 on [this page](http://www.geoplugin.com/examples) should help.

Comment: A better way to do this would be to have the script in a separate js file and use wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `wp_enqueue_script` function to include your JS scripts.
For more information about this function, check this Codex Page : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

If you only want to load this scripts on specified pages, you should use Conditional Tags : http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Conditions_For_...

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
    // blog page
} else {
    //everything else
}
```